# How to get current date in file name?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am generating report everyday through SSRS. I am trying to get current date as file name when ever the job runs and file created.

Like this ID_report_03-31-2014

I have tried echo %date% %time% and @ExecutionTime but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you saving the report to a fileshare with the subscription?

Comment: Yes i am doing through subscription

Answer (score 12):

The main option with a file share subscription is to add `@timestamp` to the file name.

From [File Share Delivery in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159264%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> An alternative approach to creating unique files for every delivery is
>   to include a timestamp in the file name. To do this, add the
>   @timestamp variable to the file name (for example,
>   CompanySales@timestamp). With this approach, the file name is unique
>   by definition, so it will never be overwritten.

I don't know if this is *exactly* what you are after, since it will include a time component, but as far as a standard SSRS subscription goes your options are limited.

**Edit after comment**

You don't have a lot of control over the format here.

On the MS forums one of there support suggests using Data Driven Subscriptions to get more control:

[Can we edit @timestamp variable in SSRS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81f47009-946a-4ebc-be43-7690236e829b/can-we-edit-timestamp-variable-in-ssrs):

> In this case, we can define the filename with timestamp in database
>   and then use Data-Driven Subscriptions to delivey the report.

But that seems a poor option to me, but is the only suggestion out there that I can see.

Comment: Thanks for replay
I have used that i am getting file name like this ID_report_2014_04_02_170452.xls
And i need this ID_report_03-31-2014 
Is there any way that i can modify timestamp ?

Comment: Added a bit more detail, but I don't really see any useful suggestions I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that problem using Data Driven Subscription.
I found the solution [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/appending-date-to-end-of-report-name-in-reporting-services-subscription).

Comment: Page is now 404.

Comment: This link is broken. Can you please repost the solution?

Comment: @KenD here is the link: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/appending-date-to-end-of-report-name-in-reporting-services-subscription