# SSRS Subscription File Name w/ Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a series of reports that run at different schedules (hourly, daily, weekly, etc) 
The reports are saved to a share \unc\reports\department\

report

report_1

report_2

report_3

As this is the only way to create a new version.

My question is if there is a way to append either execution time or even just the date so the end user can see the time the report was generated.
Currently it is done by looking at date modified properties, which is Ok, but not ideal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current date in file name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823519/how-to-get-current-date-in-file-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can capture the runtime with @timestamp variable and stamp it with your Report filename. Append @timestamp with your filename in the subcription manager as shown below.

[image: Subscription Manager for SSRS]

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is possible, you would need to use a data driven subscription. Here is a good how-to on it:

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/briankmcdonald/bidn-blog/1255/appending-date-to-end-of-report-name-in-reporting-services-subscription