# SSRS add timestamp to filename

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add the timestamp to my SSRS reports filename. I have seen online you can do this by adding @timestamp to the filename. But when I try to do this I get an error saying I can't use any reserved characters in my filename. Would anyone know a work around or another way o do this?

Comment: If you refer to name a file generated through a subscription, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400831/ssrs-subscription-file-name-w-date)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to find the subscription manager. would you know where that's located?

Comment: In Report Server site, look for your report, drop down the option list and select subscribe... then choose Windows File Share. A form like the added in the answer I referenced previously is presented.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions but I'm new to this. what do you mean by the report server site?

Comment: If you want to delivery the report in a specific format and location, You have to deploy it to a Report Server, once deployed create a subscription and use the `@timestamp` variable in the subscription manager. You can't set the `@timestamp` in the RDL filename.