# SSRS Report Subscription - send to FTP

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a few reports that send emails with the reports attached.
The reports are in Excel format, and run Daily.

Was wondering if it is possible to send the report to an FTP site.
If possible, also add to the name of the file prefix or suffix with the date (no need for Time).

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Your  question is too broad right now! Pls read [ask] and provide a [mcve]! Thank you!

Comment: Edited post a bit, but not sure what else to do to focus issue...

Comment: What did you try? What is your expected result. How do you plan to achieve your goal, [so] is not a coding service. That is why i referred to [ask].

Comment: I see. I thought what I asked was pretty straight forward.

But to answer your questions:

Q: What did you try?
A: I don't know how to achieve what I need, so did not try anything. Yet.

Q: What is your expected result?
A: Have Report run on schedule, and instead of delivering Report with Excel attached to Email, to have it uploaded to an FTP.

Q: How do you plan to achieve your goal?
A: If I knew that I would not have asked here...

I did not ask for Code. First I need to know if it's possible. Then I will go to the next step of asking how, from whomever says its.

Comment: If you don't know then you have to learn about programming. Once more, [so] is not a coding service! BTW: You should update your question rather than refining your question in a comment...

Comment: Hmm... Really not trying to be difficult here :(
My original question was if it was or was not possible. Did not ask/request anything about coding. That's it.
If it was, then we could discuss on how, and if coding was involved then your comment would have been relevant.
But will take your comment to heart if/when I have Coding questions in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible out of the box (we're looking into option as well - currently favouring some kind of DMZ with the recipient doing and FTP pull).

One option we've found is using VBScript to push via SFTP. See here for more details: https://skamie.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/send-ssrs-subscription-files-to-secured-ftp/

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

I saw that it says the following:
"We scheduled the report to run at specific time, say 10:00am GMT and delivered it to a windows share."

Does this mean the file is saved in a Windows environment?

Comment: Yeah - you can change the subscription to save to a network share. You need to use the full UNC path for the share, and the user you specify needs write access to that folder.  See here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159264.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need the date and time in the name of the report output, you can use the [@timestamp variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms159264(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#:%7E:text=this%2C%20add%20the-,%40timestamp,-variable%20to%20the) anywhere in the filename and it will be replaced with `yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss`.

If you absolutely must remove the timestamp, you will need to use a data-driven subscription and set the filename as part of your query.  This SO question has more details: [How to get current date in file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823519/how-to-get-current-date-in-file-name)

As for getting the output to SFTP, you could use this: https://deztec.com/products/sftp-destination/